# When I use Extjs to define a FormPanel and want to do a submit action, a js error occured

Tags: extjs

I debugged with chrome explorer, the error info is:

> *ext-all.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.*

I have tried three ways to submit:

```js
// First way
var subform = uploadform.getForm();
subform.submit(function(){}) 

// Second way
var subform = uploadform.getForm();
subform.doAction('submit', {});

// Third way
uploadform.submit(function(){})
```

But all there code cause the same error.
I need some help.Thanks.

Comment: post your form code

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Question solved! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer that solved the question.
An item is defined like this:
{
xtype: 'filefield',
inputType: 'file', 
... //other properties
}
I remove this line: "inputType: 'file'", and change "xtype: 'filefield'" to "xtype: 'fileuploadfield'". Then the question is solved. I don't know why but it works.